# Kafka Consumer + Schema Registry dynamic subject name

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, apache-kafka-streams

I have multiple topics A, B and C which I am fanning into topic X using Kafka Streams.
Topics A, B and C are registered as subjects in the schema registry using the default topic name strategy. The streaming is quite dumb in that it just fans messages in without ensuring they conform to the schema in the registry but it adds a ORIGINAL_TOPIC_NAME header to the message to indicate it came from topic A, B or C.

I then have Kafka Consumer consuming from topic X. This topic is not registered with the schema registry. The Kafka Consumer is where I use the KafkaAvroDeserialiser along with the `schema.registry.url` to consume using the registry. I was planning on the consumer here doing the check against the registry but using the ORIGINAL_TOPIC_NAME header as the subject. However I'm not sure if I have control on the consumer to make it use a kafka header to resolve the subject name since the subject name strategy is something you feed into the consumer at initialisation time.

Any ideas?

Answer (score -1):

The strategy is passed to the deserializer

The deserialize function only has access to the incoming byte array of the key or value, and the topic name, not the headers.

There is a header deserializer that can be set, but it isn't used within the call path of the key/value deserializer.

---

The workaround would be to use ByteArrayDeserializer for the key/value, optionally extract your header manually, get the schema ID using logic like this

```
ByteBuffer bb = ByteBuffer.wrap(value); // or key
if (bb.get() != 0x0) {
    // not a valid encoded Schema Registry record 
}
int schemaId = bb.getInt();
// Completely ignores the subject 
Schema schema = schemaRegistryClient.getId(schemaId);
// TODO: continue to deserialize the key/value byte array
```